# Inserting & removing rows in a MySQL database without multiple queries

Tags: mysql, query-optimization, sql-insert, sql-delete

**Check this example before reading the question** - http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fcf3e/8

The following data comes from a form, the user simply removed a product from a special offer.

```
Array(
    'special_offer_id' => 1,
    'product_ids' => Array(
        0 => 1,
        0 => 2
    )
)
```

Originally I wanted to use this query...

```
REPLACE INTO `foo` VALUES (1, 1), (2, 1);
```

But this won't remove the product that the user removed - only update the others.

So I'm forced to perform 2 queries...

```
DELETE FROM `foo` WHERE `special_offer_id` = 1;
INSERT INTO `foo` VALUES (1, 1), (2, 1);
```

Is there a better way to do this without having to perform 2 queries?

**Example**: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!2/fcf3e/8

Comment: What is wrong with multiple queries? Perhaps the best way to go is to have stored procedures.

Comment: Nothing wrong with them, I just wanted to know if there was a preferred way of doing it.

Comment: Why do you think that REPLACE does not remove records? Check this with SELECT ROW_COUNT() query. Your PK is composite key (product_id, special_offer_id).

Comment: Because `REPLACE INTO` will only `UPDATE` the 2 records in the array and ignore the one that was removed.

Comment: REPLACE statement checks unique fields firstly (`product_id` and `special_offer_id`), then removes and insert new record, or just insert new one. The field `special_offer_id` is not unique in your case.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think it is possible within MySQL to combine DML statements. I do know that Oracle and MSSQL have the merge function for this but I think MySQL doens't have this function but i'm not quite sure about that.

Looking at your fiddle and what the code actually does I've came up with a different approach. If you loop through your array of data which is present and put the output into 1 variable and use the delete to delete the rows which do not match.

Here's an example based on your sqlfiddle (note that the array is not valid as it is not named correctly in the fiddle)

```
// Declare var and fill with array result
$exists = '';

for ($c = 0; $c < count($array); c++)
{
    if ($c == (count($array) -1))
    {
      $exists .= $array[$c]['product_ids'];
    }
    else
    {
      $exists .= $array[$c]['product_ids'].',';
    }
}
```

Then instead of doing two queries, you can do it with one

```
DELETE FROM `foo` WHERE `special_offer_id` NOT IN ('.$exists.');
```